# how to make the div's fill in available space automatically

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this `html` page:

[jsFidlle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3ufmqoo5/)

I want the boxes to fill in the available space automatically with the boxes having same width but different heights.

Pretty much as the notes in  [google keep](https://www.google.com/keep/)

Comment: both the links are same one

Comment: **[Like this here?](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3ufmqoo5/3/)**

Comment: oh thnx.. i want my boxes to appear as  the notes in the google keep look like and not their main webpage!

Comment: Rao: Yeah this is pretty much it but i need the boxes to have different heights..

Comment: Oh you need to fill the area, instead of increasing it?

Comment: Use [jquery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: do you need multiple columns? If not, just set `width:100%` on `.components`. If you do, try flexbox (if you don't need to support older browsers). https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ I used it to create a fluid layout with boxes always taking up the space available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it would be helpful to you.

https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/

This is compatible with bootstrap.

Comment: That's exactly what I want.. Thnx! (unfortunately i am new so i can't up-vote nor approve two answers..)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I think you can mark as correct this answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have it using CSS. You will have to use something like [jQuery Masanory](https://github.com/desandro/masonry)

Comment: On [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn), you could with some kind of limitations (vertically ordered e.g): https://jsfiddle.net/ztpxqsau/

Answer (score 0):

Cant seem to achieve the effect jsfiddle but this is how i would go about it

```
<div class="which-ever-class-name"> //surrounding the two divs
<div class="components">Help us find a visionary financier!</div>
<div class="components">Kamusi Here:<br>
Instant translation among the languages in our system (arriving soon at 50+)
<ul>
<li>Chrome extension: ready to ship (pending server)
<li>Mobile app: we need a day or three to join Here! and WordUp!
<li>Facebook Messenger: needs some easy hacks
<li>Other platforms: we've got the back end, just need the implementation horsepower
</ul>
</div>
</div>//end surrounding div
```

and in css

```
.components{
  height:100%;
 }
```

What this should do is set the components height to fill parent(`which-ever-class-name`) height, and parent height in turn will be set by the longest component.